# Issue importing a class from the same directory

Tags: class, import

Sorry if this seems like a very trivial question, but I have been trying for a while to import a class from a separate file in the same directory for some time. I have been using "from file_name import Class" The code works when it is all in the same file, it is only when it is split that I get the error message that "question is not defined". Here is the code in the file containing the class (called survey):

```
class AnonymousSurvey():
    def __init__(self, question):
        self.question = question
        self.responses = []
    def show_question(self):
        print(question)
    def collect_response(self,new_response):
        self.responses.append(new_response)
    def show_results(self):
        print("Survey results")
        number=1
        for x in self.responses:
            print(str(number)+". " + x)
            number+=1
```

and here is the code which is using the class:

```
from survey import AnonymousSurvey

question = "What language can you speak?"

my_survey = AnonymousSurvey(question)

my_survey.show_question()

print("If you would like to quit press q")
while True:
    response=input("languages")
    if response == "q":
       break
    my_survey.collect_response(response)
   
    
my_survey.show_results()
```

Sorry if this seems very trivial I am very new to coding and I would be really grateful for any help as I have been stuck with this for quite some time :)

Answer (score 0):

> I get the error message that "question is not defined".
>
> ```
>     def show_question(self):
>         print(question)
> ```

Indeed `question` is not defined in this function; surely you meant `self.question`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried that and it came up with this error message: "No module named 'survey.py'; 'survey' is not a package"

Comment: Oh the file name is already survey.py it is saved as a python file sorry I didn't specify that in the question!

Comment: I tried that, but it is still saying that name question is not defined. Here is the full error message: "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Ahmed/OneDrive/Documents/Python Scripts/Practicing files/Testing code/language_survey.py", line 7, in <module>
    my_survey.show_question()
  File "C:/Users/Ahmed/OneDrive/Documents/Python Scripts/Practicing files/Testing code\survey.py", line 6, in show_question
    print(question)
NameError: name 'question' is not defined"  Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't pay enough attention to the error message; I corrected the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your help that makes sense now!